# AngularJS 1.3 ng-repeat not updating with new database addition

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble getting my listings page to refresh when a new item has been added. The code below successfully adds a new document to the database from a detail page and then returns to the listings page but the listings page is not updated until I manually press F5.

I have tried adding a `$route.reload()` statement but that did not help.  The problem fixes itself after a few times.  In other words the first one or two times a new document is added the listing page does not refresh and show the new item but by the third consecutive addition the listings page will start to refresh every time.  I am using Firefox but see the same problem in other browsers.

What code am I missing to make sure that the listings page `ng-repeat` will re-run after a new item is added to the database?  I have the same problem elsewhere in my app when I remove items from the database, the listings page `ng-repeat` does not re-fire and show the updated list.

```
securityApp.controller('newDocumentController', 
   function ($scope, $location, $route, addNewDocumentFactory) {

      $scope.addNewDocument = function () {
         addNewDocumentFactory.create($scope.document);
         alert('New Document has been added');
         $location.path('/documents');
      };
});

securityApp.factory('addNewDocumentFactory', 
   function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/api/Documents/', {}, {
         create: { method: 'POST' }
      });
});



<tr ng-repeat="document in documents | orderBy:['-date', '-documentNumber'] | filter:searchText | filter: {date: searchDate}">
   various td elements here..
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you using some cache system ? How do you load your documents in your listing page ?

Comment: I'm not using any caching.  The listings page uses the ng-repeat listed above.

Comment: $http.get('/api/Documents/')
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.documents = response.data;
            });

Comment: The above `tr ng-repeat` template is associated with which controller? Which template and which controller are affiliated with `/documents` and how? ngroute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use promises since this is an async call;

```
securityApp.controller('newDocumentController', 
   function ($scope, $location, $route, addNewDocumentFactory) {

      $scope.addNewDocument = function () {
         addNewDocumentFactory.create($scope.document).$promise.then(function () {
             alert('New Document has been added');
             $location.path('/documents');
         });
      };
});
```

Comment: $scope.addNewDocument = function () {
        addNewDocumentFactory.create($scope.document).$promise.then(function () {
            alert('New Document has been added');
            $location.path('/documents');
            $route.reload();
        });
    };

Comment: Nice, thank you!  I added the $promise.then and the $route.reload() and that seems to be working with getting the documents listing page to display the newly added document.